# Is this style of using Thread pool with tornado ok?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tornado, python-asyncio

So I create a class variable called executor in my class

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(100)
```

and instead of having functions and methods and using decorators, I simply use following line to handle my blocking tasks(like io and hash creation and....) in my async methods

```
result = await to_tornado_future(self.executor.submit(blocking_method, param1, param2)
```

I decided to use this style cause

1- decorators are slower by nature

2- there is no need for extra methods and functions

3- it workes as expected and creates no threads before it needed

Am I right ? Please use reasons(I want to know if the way I use, is slower or uses more resources or....)

**Update**

Based on Ben answer, my above approach was not correct
so I ended up using following function as needed, I think it's the best way to go

```
def pool(pool_executor, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    new_future = Future()
    result_future = pool_executor.submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    result_future.add_done_callback(lambda f: new_future.set_result(f.result()))
    return new_future
```

usage:

```
result = await pool(self.executor, time.sleep, 3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is safe as long as all your blocking methods are thread-safe. Since you mentioned doing IO in these threads, I'll point out that doing file IO here is fine but all network IO in Tornado must occur on the IOLoop's thread.

Why do you say "decorators are slower by nature"? Which decorators are slower than what? Some decorators have no performance overhead at all (although most do have some runtime cost). `to_tornado_future(executor.submit())` isn't free either. (BTW, I think you want `tornado.gen.convert_yielded` instead of `tornado.platform.asyncio.to_tornado_future`. `executor.submit` doesn't return an `asyncio.Future`).

As a general rule, running `blocking_method` on a thread pool is going to be *slower* than just calling it directly. You should do this only when `blocking_method` is likely to block for long enough that you want the main thread free to do other things in the meantime.

Comment: I see your point about to_tornado_future and executor.submit, but How can I use executor.submit within an async def and await expression to get result ? I think it's not possible using convert_yielded,Am I missing something ?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. `convert_yielded` doesn't work here but `to_tornado_future` does. Maybe the special-casing of `concurrent.futures.Future` in `convert_yielded` isn't worth it.

Comment: Do you mean just the network I/O that directly involves Tornado should happen on `IOLoop`'s thread, or any and all network I/O (e.g. using `boto3`)? If the latter, why so?

Comment: All I/O that uses Tornado must happen on the IOLoop's thread; any I/O that doesn't use the IOLoop must happen on some other thread.